# Failed to pass a variable in an IIEF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm following an angular.js tutorial in which a controller has been decalred in a seperate file within an IIEF to prevent poluating the global scope. Simple vanilla javascript was used in that tutorial but i chose to use ES6 (and also to use webpack as a bundler).

this is how originally the controller code was written without ES6 and webpack(then the file was simply referenced in a script tag in html)

```
(function(){

    "use strict";

    angular.module("ngClassifieds")
        .controller("classifiedsCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
            $scope.name = "Ryann";                      
        }]);
})();
```

and this is how i wrote that controller code in its file with a commonjs export  and also as this file won't be simply referenced in html but its function will be called using commonjs require and i had to pass the main app module as a parameter to its function:

```
module.exports = (ngClassifieds => {
    "use strict";

    console.log('ngClassifieds : ' + ngClassifieds);

    ngClassifieds.controller("classifiedsCtrl", $scope => {
        $scope.name = "Ryann";
    });
})(ngClassifieds);
```

and this is how i called it from another file:

```
import angular from 'angular'; 
import classifiedsCtrl from './../components/classifieds.ctrl';


const ngClassifieds = angular.module('ngClassifieds', []); 
classifiedsCtrl(ngClassifieds);
```

but i got this serie of errors in the brower console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ngClassifieds is not defined
angular.js?3437:4640Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngClassifieds due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngClassifieds' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ngClassifieds
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:68:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:2082:17)
    at ensure (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:2006:38)
    at module (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:2080:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:4617:22)
    at forEach (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:321:20)
    at loadModules (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:4601:5)
    at createInjector (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:4523:19)
    at doBootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:1758:20)
    at bootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/index.js:60:2), <anonymous>:1779:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngClassifieds&p1=Er…F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Findex.js%3A60%3A2)%2C%20%3Canonymous%3E%3A1779%3A12)
```

i don't know why passing the variable in the IIEF wasn't successful and i also wonder if using the IIEF itself is still worthwhile.

Comment: Since you are using ES6 (or commonjs) modules, you don't need an IIFE for scope at all.

Comment: Why would you not place the `angular.module('ngClassifieds'…` call in that external file as well?

Comment: @Bergi, i was following technics used by egghead, he passed the main app module as a variable,  i supposed it's the good way to do it but what you said is very wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to export a regular function, and not use an IIFE:

```
module.exports = ngClassifieds => {
    "use strict";

    console.log('ngClassifieds : ' + ngClassifieds);

    ngClassifieds.controller("classifiedsCtrl", $scope => {
        $scope.name = "Ryann";
    });
};
```

Comment: i will admit IIEF cannot be used in context of commonjs export

Comment: @Bardelman: Of course they can. It was just not the right thing to use in your situation. You wanted to export a function, but instead you called a function and exported its return value.